# How to apply a function on a list of lists two at a time?

Tags: python, list, apply, sublist

I have a list of lists like this:

```
all_lists = [list0, list1, list2, list3, ....., listn]
```

And a function like this which takes two arguments from this all_lists.

```
def function(list0, list1):
    do stuff
```

The function will keep taking arguments from that all_lists by moving the index by 1 until it reaches to listn.

Is there an efficient way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: two arguments mean all  combinations  like `function(list0 ,list1)` or `function(list0 ,list2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` the list with itself and pass arguments in a loop.

```
for l1, l2 in zip(all_lists[:-1], all_lists[1:]): # or zip(all_lists, all_lists[1:])
    function(l1, l2)
```

---

MVCE:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i, j in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    print(i, j)

1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Comment: You don't need the `[:-1]`, so at best it's a VCE :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann From the Zen of Python: `Explicit is better than implicit.` ... :p

Comment: Meh, that's only the second one. First is `Beautiful is better than ugly.`

Comment: @StefanPochmann ahaha Nitpick accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want with all possible combination, you can use itertools **[combination](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)** method

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
>>> 
>>> for _lst in itertools.combinations(a, 2):
...      print _lst
... 
([1, 2], [2, 3])
([1, 2], [3, 4])
([2, 3], [3, 4])
```

For your **Code**:

```
all_lists = [list0, list1, list2, list3, ....., listn]

for l1,l2 in itertools.combinations(all_list , 2):
    print l1,l2
    # do stuff
```